# await выбрасывает из функции и ставит ее в конец очереди

Tags: c#, async-await

```
private void nOLIMITToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account.rows = 34;
    a.RequestFile(client, 6);
    objectListView1.SetObjects(acc.InitializeAccs());
}
```

В моей голове должны по очереди выполняться функции `RequestFile` и `SetObjects`, но когда дело доходит до `await`,

```
async public void RequestFile(TelegramClient client, int button_number)
{
    await client.SendMessageAsync(peer, "Menu");
    var po = GetHistory(client);
    int msg_id = GetMessageId(po);
    //...
}
```

программа выходит из функции, выполняет функцию `SetObjects`, и только потом продолжает выполнение `RequestFile`

Если же `await` убрать, функция перестает корректно работать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280808/c-sharp-async-and-wait-not-working

Comment: У вас функция RequestFile асинхронная. И значит после вызова она тут же вернет управление. У вас немного другие понятия исправьте их

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не ожидаете асинхронную операцию `RequestFile` с помощью `await`, вы ее выполняете в режиме "запустил и забыл", и вы не можете ее ожидать, потому что она `async void`.

Чтобы можно было ожидать, операция должна быть `async Task`, верная реализация может выглядеть вот так:

```cs
private async void nOLIMITToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account.rows = 34;
    await a.RequestFile(client, 6);
    objectListView1.SetObjects(acc.InitializeAccs());
}

public async Task RequestFile(TelegramClient client, int button_number)
{
    await client.SendMessageAsync(peer, "Menu");
    var po = GetHistory(client);
    int msg_id = GetMessageId(po);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Я с телефона, ответил бы. Вот только набирать тут долго. Знал что ответишь + от меня.